# I need to store data from HTML table to MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a project with HTML, CSS, PHP and MySQL. The project is an online vegetable shop which is nearly an e-commerce site. I need to store data from a HTML table (my cart) to MySQL database using PHP. The table looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZxD4.png

The code for "cart" is:

```
'<?php
    include("session.php");
    include_once("config.php");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>View shopping cart</title>

    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
    <body>
    <h1 align="center">View Cart</h1>
    <div class="cart-view-table-back">
    <form method="post" action="buy.php">
    <table id="myTable" width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">                        <thead><tr><th>Sl_no</th><th>Username</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Name</th>        <th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th>Remove</th></tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]))
        {
            $total = 0;
            $fl=1;
            $b = 0; 
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
            {

                $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
                $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
                $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
                $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
                $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); 

                $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; 


                echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
                echo '<td>'.$fl.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$user.'</td>';
                echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2"
    name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$product_price.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$subtotal.'</td>';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]"
    value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                $fl++;
                $total = ($total + $subtotal); 
            }
            echo$fl;
            $grand_total = $total; 

    }


        ?>


      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit">buy</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php 
    $current_url =
    urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo $current_url; ?>" />
    </form>

    </div>

  </body>
    </html>'
```

And I am using a PHP page(`buy.php`) to store all the data in the database. The code for `buy.php` is:

```
    '<?php

    include('session.php');
    $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
    $total=0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
    {

        $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
            $sql="INSERT INTO cart (Uname,TotalCost,veg_id,quantity) 
VALUES('$user','$total','$product_code','$product_qty')";
    if($con->query($sql)==true){
        echo"data inserted successfully";
    }
    echo"<br><br><a href='index_2.php'> Return to Your Dashboard</a>
    <a href='buy_veg.php'> Buy More Items</a>";

    ?>'
```

The problem is that this `buy.php` page is actually storing the last record to the database. Image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AgmH.png

I want to store all the cart items to the database. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: you need to insert values on  each iteration so just move the query execution part into inside the foreach

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{

    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
}
        $sql="INSERT INTO cart (Uname,TotalCost,veg_id,quantity) 
VALUES('$user','$total','$product_code','$product_qty')";
```

Your insertion query is outside of `foreach()`, and the variables inside the loop are overwritten on each iteration. Means that they only hold the last value in it and you are inserting only that.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. My problem is now solved. without your help I couldn't complete my project. Thank you all for repairing my code..

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert values on each iteration so just move the query execution part into inside the foreach .

Note: why it's storing last values only means . foreach overwriting the variable on each iteration so last iteration values is setup into variable values so it's storing last iteration values only .

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{

    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
        $sql="INSERT INTO cart (Uname,TotalCost,veg_id,quantity) 
        VALUES('$user','$total','$product_code','$product_qty')";
        if($con->query($sql)==true){
          echo"data inserted successfully";
          }
}
```